# How to log the ip addresses trying to connect to a port?

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, firewall

Is it possible to log all IP addresses that trying to connect or connected to port "5901" in Linux Debian?

How can i do that?

Comment: why down vote as soon as question posted?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but one of the reasons for a downvote on SF is that the question "does not show any research effort" and I'm sorry, but yours doesn't.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could do it using iptables

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5901 -m state --state NEW  -j LOG --log-level 1 --log-prefix "New Connection "
```

This will log new tcp connections on port 5901 to `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kernel.log` like this

> Dec 12 07:52:48 u-10-04 kernel: [591690.935432] New Connection IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:2e:78:f1:00:0c:29:eb:43:22:08:00 SRC=192.168.254.181 DST=192.168.254.196 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40815 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=36972 DPT=5901 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

Answer (score 17):

if it's short term - this should do:

```
tcpdump -n -i eth0 -w file.cap "port 5901"
```

alternatively you can use the log target of iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5901 -j LOG --log-prefix '** guests **'--log-level 4
```

this might flood your logs

Answer (score -2):

you can use `netstat` with options -v,-n,-t, -a

e.g.
`netstat -anp | :8080 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l`
OR

```
root@user:/home# netstat -vatn

Active Internet connections (servers and established)

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.174:8080      192.168.1.126:53021     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.174:8080      192.168.1.126:32950     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.174:8080      192.168.1.126:39634     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.174:8080      192.168.1.126:59300     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.174:8080      192.168.1.188:49551     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.174:9090      192.168.1.126:37865     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.174:9090      192.168.1.188:51411     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.174:8080      192.168.1.126:50824     ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Since that command is not producing a log of all the IP addresses, it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Also, "ESTABLISHED" will only have happened when they successfully connected, so this doesn't show who is *attempting* to connect (for example, if the port isn't open, they will all fail).