# Which log file can I use for server port analytics?

Tags: linux, logging, port, analytics, parsing

Ideally I'd like to use piwik to track conversions from ads to server connections on port 5000 and port 5001 but I highly doubt that is even possible.

I'm willing to settle for [ipaddress,time connected, time disconnected] and I'm fairly positive I will be able to code a parser that outputs the information in that format.

So my question is. What log file records server connections and port numbers. Is there a log file in Debian Linux that I can parse to gain insight on how users are connecting to and using my server? Are there tools already built for this type of information collection?

Comment: Might not give you the referrer, but you could use this approach for the port information:  http://serverfault.com/questions/457340/how-to-log-the-ip-addresses-trying-to-connect-to-a-port

Comment: @Mary does iptables logging also track disconnects? In the example you linked to the MAC address would be the unique identifier or is that the local MAC address of the server?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to log disconnects (would actually be resets or fin packets depending on the situation).  Some discussion of this over here:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126937/can-iptables-be-used-to-monitor-tcp-timeouts-resets-system-wide.      And logging dropped packets:  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/iptables-log-packets/

You can log the MAC address, but the format may be different than you expect:  https://access.redhat.com/solutions/70465