# Can iptables log all type of tcp connection?

Tags: iptables, logging, tcp

Can iptables log tcp Split-Handshake and Simultaneous-Open connections as well as tcp Three Way Handshake?

[Here](https://nmap.org/misc/split-handshake.pdf) is these two kind of tcp connection descriptions.

[Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/457340/how-to-log-the-ip-addresses-trying-to-connect-to-a-port) I find how to log new tcp connections on specific port, is it also log these to kind of tcp connections?